# iScroll not horizontally scrolling entire width of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, trigger.io, iscroll

iScroll is not horizontally scrolling the entire width of a div. It stops at the wrong width value which I can't seem to find where that value originates from. The main scroll div width is not changing so I don't need to call `refresh()`.

Essentially I've got a div inside the scroll div that is changing size so divs inside can be changed to absolute position while other divs inside are initially floated right. I didn't want to use iScroll but it's necessary since I'm building an HTML5 iOS WebView app with Trigger.io.

http://jsfiddle.net/simpleshadow/wQQEM/15/

```
var myScrollers = [];
$(function() {

    var scrolls = $('.scrolls');

    $.each(scrolls, function(i, value) {
        var self = this,
            imageDiv = $(this).find('.imageDiv'),
            imageWrapper = $(this).find('.imageWrapper'),
            images = $(this).find('.imageDiv img'),
            width = 0;

        $.each(images, function(index, value){
            width += $(this).width();
        });
        imageDiv.css('right', (-$(this).width()+images.first().width()) + 'px');
        imageWrapper.width(images.first().width());

        myScrollers[i] = new iScroll($(this)[0], { 
            hScroll: true, 
            vScroll: false, 
            hScrollbar: false, 
            vScrollbar: false,
            onScrollMove: function(e){
                var x = 0;
                -myScrollers[i].x >= 0 ? x = -myScrollers[i].x : x = 0;
                updateWindow($(self), x);
            },
            onScrolling: function(e) {
                var x = 0;
                -myScrollers[i].x >= 0 ? x = -myScrollers[i].x : x = 0;
                updateWindow($(self), x);
            }
        });

    });

    // Update the window
    function updateWindow(el, x) {

        var x = x,
            width = 0,
            imageDiv = el.find('.imageDiv'),
            imageWrapper = el.find('.imageWrapper'),
            images = el.find('.imageDiv img');

        el.find('.imageDiv, .imageDiv img').css({
            height: (x/160)*75+75 >= 150 ? 150 : (x/160)*75+75
        });

        for (var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++) {
            width += $(images[i]).width();
            if (imageWrapper.width() >= width && i !== 0) {
                $(images[i]).addClass('out').css({
                    left: (width-$(images[i]).outerWidth(true)) + 'px'
                });
            } else {
                i !== 0 && $(images[i]).removeClass('out').css({
                    left: 0
                });
            }
        }

        if (x+images.first().width() <= width) imageWrapper.width(x+images.first().width());
        imageDiv.css('right', (-$(this).width()+images.first().width()) + 'px');

    }

});
```

Comment: I managed to discover that if I set the `.imageDiv` to `width: 1368px;` it looks perfect. This works but eventually the contents will be varied so I need to figure out where this value is coming from. Here's the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/simpleshadow/wQQEM/18/

Comment: I was determining the scrolling div `.imageDiv' width based on the wrong elements and have fixed it. Here's an example of it in working action: http://jsfiddle.net/simpleshadow/wQQEM/22/